# Rand function with two different result

Tags: c++, random, qt-creator

my question is about rand function in c++
please check this, why this generate different results:

```
int a = 2 * rand()%5; // result = 0
int a = 2 * ( rand()%5 ); // result = 6
```

number 1
[image]

number 2
[image]

Comment: So you're asking why the `rand()` function is return random numbers every time you execute/call it? Thats the purpose of it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Operator precedence as well. `2*rand()%5` is the same as `(2*rand())%5`.

Comment: @ralismark -- that's not precedence, it's grouping. `*` and `%` have the same precedence. They group left to right, which is why your alternate version is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding the fact that you'd rather hope that the probability of `rand()` returning a different number on the second iteration is `1 - 1 / (1 + RAND_MAX)`, the first expression is *grouped* as

```
(2 * rand()) % 5
```

which is different to the second grouping. You can see for example that the value of the second expression is always even.

`*` and `%` have the same *precedence*, so *associativity* comes into play, which for both operators is left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's literally the purpose of `rand()`. As cppreference states :

> Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between `0` and
>   `RAND_MAX`.

You *want* it to produce different results otherwise it'd be a useless PRNG.

Plus the fact that the first expression first multiplies and then modulo's. While the second one does it in reverse.

To get the same values you have to fix your operator precedence and then call `srand` with the same seed twice right before calling `rand()`.

---

Note that you should use the `<random>` header nowadays instead of `rand()`.